# Unable to call addition method of calculator class in Main method of driver class although I am including cal.dll

Tags: c#, .net

this is the driver class in driver.cs

```
using System;
public class driver{
public static void Main(){
    int meth;
    calculator obj = new calculator();
    do
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("1. Addition\n2.Subtraction\n3.Multiplication\n4. Division\n5. Mod\n6. Square Root");
        meth=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (meth==1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1st Number=");
            double num1=double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 2st Number=");
            double num2=double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            double answer = obj.addition(num1,num2);
        }
    } while (meth!=0);
}}
```

this is the calculator class in cal.cs

```
using System;
public class calculator{

double addition(double x,double y){
return x+y;
}

double subtraction(double x,double y){
return x-y;
}

double multiplication(double x,double y){
return x*y;
}

double division(double x,double y){
return x/y;
}

double mod(double x,double y){
 return x%y;
}

double squareRoot(double x){
return Math.Sqrt(x);
}
}
```

I have created the cal.dll file using

> CSC /target:library cal.cs

then compiling the driver class

> CSC /reference:cal.dll driver.cs

everything is working fine except the

```
obj.addition(num1,num2);
```

in driver class
Need Help

Comment: What do you mean by everything is working fine? What error are you getting for that line?

Comment: error is at calling the addition function of cal class from Main method
read the description that's why I wrote it.

Comment: No, that's not what @o_weisman meant. A compiler will not say just "there is an error", it also gives you a description of the error. You forgot to read and/or paste it.

Comment: driver.cs(19.25):error 1061: 'calculator' does not contain a definition for 'addition' and no extension method 'addition' accepting a first argument of type 'calculator' could be found <are u missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your methods public to make them accessible from other classes. Apparently the error message is not very descriptive - CS1061 is also given when you attempt to call a non-public method from outside the class.

```
public double Addition(double x, double y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

I also recommend reading the [naming conventions on capitalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: compiler is saying that calculator class dont have method addition
error CS1061

Comment: I'm fairly sure that's not the error message you're getting unless you forgot to recompile something.

Comment: Apparently the error message is not very descriptive. The solution is still correct.

Comment: driver.cs(19.25):error 1061: 'calculator' does not contain a definition for 'addition' and no extension method 'addition' accepting a first argument of type 'calculator' could be found <are u missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

**Metohds of type are by default with internal protection level I just placed `public` before each method and it worked fine**

Answer (score 0):

> driver.cs(19.25):error 1061: 'calculator' does not contain a
>   definition for 'addition' and no extension method 'addition' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'calculator' could be found

As Matti Virkkunen has pointed already this is because method is `private`.

Normally if method is `private` and it is in the same project as console app, you'll get compile time error : *"method is inaccesible due to its protection level"*.

Because it's in another project it's not inaccessible but completely invisible for console app.

P.S.
You can still access your private method using reflection :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        calculator calc = new calculator();

        var addition = calc.GetType().GetMethod("addition", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic  
                                                          | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

        var result = addition.Invoke(calc, new object[] { 5, 10 });

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Output : `15`